# Can you test foreign language strings like Arabic or Russian?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My website has the ability to be viewed in different languages.  Is it possible to use sendKeys with a var that looks like this:

var arabic = "صباح الخير

I have tried using:

element(by.css(...)).sendKeys(arabic);

however question marks are the only characters sent to the text box.
Is this possible?

Comment: You should read once https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n.

Comment: @vineet I cannot change the html or js all i can do is write the test and from what I see online I cannot find documentation for testing different languages.

Comment: you should share what are going to try for further uses.

Answer (score 2):

From Protractor point of view, if you see only ??? in input or whatever you are filling the extended chars in, it is probably a bug in that webpage, because generally `sendKeys('باح الخير')` works absolutely fine.

By the way, silly question, but have you tried pasting those extended chars to input directly, without protractor?

Comment: when I try to copy and paste arabic text to sendkeys I get a bunch of question marks in place of the characters

Comment: Sounds like a problem in your text editor, try something with utf-8 support,  for example atom.

Comment: I will give that a shot, I'll let you know how it goes.